# Hiding type parameters in implementation of interface

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

Given the following Interface:

```
public interface IContext {
    TOutput get<TInput, TOutput>(TInput command);
}
```

And the following implementation:

```
public class DbContext: IContext {}

public class Repository {
    private readonly IContext _context;

    public Repository(IContext context) {...}

    public IDto get(int id) {
        var data = _context.get<IThis, IThat>(id)
        //map data to dto and return
    }
}
```

Since I'm passing the `IContext` dependency into the `Repository` class I don't want type parameters on the interface since it would lock me into using an explicit implementation of IContext. Kind of muting the point of interfaces right?

Given my constraints of not having type parameters on the `IContext` interface, how can I implement `IContext` so that I can call `_context.get(...)` in my `Repository` class instead of `_context.get<IThis, IThat>(...)`?

So in other words, I'd like the implementation of `IContext` (In this example `DBContext`) to define the type parameters for `get()` so that when the method is actually invoked the invoker doesn't need to know anything about the type parameters to be passed.

**Update**

The problem I'm trying to fix is allowing any kind of `IContext` to be passed into a repository. If I have class level type parameters on the interface then I'm restricted to only implementations of `IContext<TThis, TThat>`, which isn't ideal.

Comment: From your description, it seems the type parameters don't make sense on the `Get` method and you should move them to the interface. I don't understand your objection to not doing so, since you can have multiple implementations of `IContext<TInput, TOutput>` for specific `TInput` and `TOutput` types.

Comment: I think you're mixing up generic interfaces/classes with generic methods.  You can't define a generic method on an interface and then supply concrete types as the interface implementation itself.  You either have to make it a generic interface or you implement conrete typing when you actually call the method.

Comment: You're mixing apples and oranges.

Comment: So, you want a run-time decision (what type implementing `IContext` is passed to the constructor) to influence compile-time behavior (the type of `data`)? I don't think C# can break causality.

Comment: @Lee In the repository, if I have to explicity declare the type parameters in the constructor then I'm tying that repository to an explicit implementation of IContext. I don't want to do that

Comment: @TrevorElliott I know that, but I tried to ask the question as simply as I could for the sake of understandability. I know that I can't use concrete types for type parameters. My thought was that possibly I'm missing something and there could be some functionality in c# that I'm unaware of in regards to generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's important that an `IContext` object have a `get` function that can accept any object as the input and provide any object as the output then rather than generics, your interface method should simply use `object`:

```
public interface IContext {
    object get(object command);
}
```

(Implementors of the interface may then have a strongly typed method exposed, and use explicit interface implementation for that method.

The other possibility is that your `IContext` object knows, when accepting the `IContext` object, what the signature of the method should be.  In that case, you'd want to make the interface, and not its method, generic:

```
public interface IContext<TInput, TOutput> {
    TOutput get(TInput command);
}
```

This of course means that you couldn't have, say, a collection of objects of all sorts of different kinds of `IContext` objects; they'd need to all share a signature.  Methods accepting or returning an `IContext` object would need to either know what type the input/output should be at compile time, or would themselves need to be generic.

On a side note that may or may not be relevant to your use of the interface, you can leverage covariance and contravariance on your generic arguments, which may or may not aid in your use of the interface:

```
public interface IContext<in TInput, out TOutput>
{
    TOutput get(TInput command);
}
```

Without understanding how you expect the interface to actually be used it's unclear which would be the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you require concrete typing together with loose coupling through interface. 
Consider this:

```
public interface ICommand {}

public interface IContextOutput {}

public interface IContext
{
    IContextOutput Get(ICommand input);
}

public abstract class ContextBase<TInput, TOutput> : IContext       
    where TInput : ICommand
    where TOutput : IContextOutput
{
    IContextOutput IContext.Get (ICommand input)
    {
        if (input.GetType () != typeof(TInput))
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("input");
        }

        return Get((TInput)input);
    }

    protected abstract TOutput Get(TInput command);     
}
```

And then derive all the *contexts* from the abstract class.